# Optimize subquery join order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query - but it's taking a super long time.
I read on wikipedia that the join order may be a factor:

> The performance of a query plan is determined largely by the order in which the tables are joined. For example, when joining 3 tables A, B, C of size 10 rows, 10,000 rows, and 1,000,000 rows, respectively, a query plan that joins B and C first can take several orders-of-magnitude more time to execute than one that joins A and C first

I'm trying to get TV shows an actor has been on through their episodes.

My query looks like this:

```
select distinct e.show_id
  from episodes e
  where e.id IN
  (select c.episode_id
  from   contributions c
  where  c.person_id = #{@person.id})
")
```

The column count for each is:

1. 2,500,000 episodes
2. 600,000 contributions
3. 40,000 shows
4. 20,000 people

Am I on the right track or should I be doing joins?  This query sometimes takes over 10 seconds on heroku even though everything has an index.

Comment: You might need to learn about indexes http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JOIN instead of nested select and IN. Something like that:

```
SELECT distinct e.show_id
  FROM episodes e
  JOIN contributions c
    ON e.id = c.episode_id
  WHERE c.person_id = @person.id
```

Comment: Also, if it is frequent case, add correct indexing to your tables.

Comment: Is this selecting e.show_id from ALL episodes first?  Or is it narrowing it down to just the episodes from the join?  It's still taking a long time.